# VNC viewer has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, router, 64-bit, vnc

Recently, my VNC viewer has stopped working. I know the server computer is working right because I can connect to it from anywhere except from my home office; from there no computer will connect, even my laptop that does connect from any other remote location.

Is there some obscure router setting that might be preventing the viewer from 'seeing' the server?

I am able to ping the location where the server is, by the way - just can't connect!

Comment: The title of this question does not match the question itself.  Please provide more information on the configuration of the network in question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your home network is blocking the VNC port (590x where x is the display number). Ping uses a different port number, so ping getting thru seems to confirm your addressing is ok. Check the firewalls on your router (which might have been configured by your ISP). Some security checks block VNC traffic by default, so this is semi-reasonable.